# Packing the Project didn't create nupkg file (Visual Studio 2022)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

I followed this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio?tabs=netcore-cli
for creating a nupkg file locally for my project (until run the pack command).

Steps to reproduce:

1. Created a project (and added the code) - net 5.0
2. Right Click on the project and then left click on pack
3. Message from the build:
   ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

But, my nupkg file wasn't created, what could cause this issue?

Update: I tried cleaning the solution then packing it again and it still didn't help.

In addition, I tried to run it with:

```
donet pack
```

and I got these message in verbose mode:

1>Project "PROJECT_PATH" on node 1 (Restore target(s)).
1>_GetAllRestoreProjectPathItems:
Determining projects to restore...
Restore:
Committing restore...
Assets file has not changed. Skipping assets file writing. Path: PROJECT_PATH\obj\project.assets.json
Restored PROJECT_PATH\PROJECT.csproj (in 39 ms).

NuGet Config files used:
NUGET_CONFIG_PATH

Feeds used:
https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

MY_PATH\NuGetPackages\

PROJECT_PATH
All projects are up-to-date for restore.
1>Done Building Project "PROJECT_PATH\PROJECT.csproj" (Restore target(s)).

Comment: What guide?  What did you do?  Your question should, minimally, explain how someone can reproduce your results.

Comment: I added the guide, thanks!

Comment: Yes, you added the guide, but we have no idea how to reproduce what you did.  I don't mean to sound sarcastic but the problem could be anything at all, like maybe you didn't press the enter key, who knows.  The details are critically important, is what I'm trying to say.  And, you should try to make this as clear for us to diagnose as possible.  Otherwise I'm looking at:  Q: "what could cause the issue?":  A:  "maybe you made a mistake."  Again, I'm not trying to be sarcastic, I'm trying to illustrate how little information you put in your question for us to go on.

Comment: @Wyck I added the steps, I didn't add them at first because they're pretty basic.

Comment: @Wyck According to the above guide, what I did supposed to create the nupkg file.
Can you elaborate your answer?

Answer (score 4):

Problem Solved:

Xunit preventing from packing the Project,

In order to pack a project with Xunit, you need to add to the csproj file the:

```
<IsPackable>true</IsPackable>
```

Comment: Had the same issue with VS2022 .net6 though I wasn't using xunit this still fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have no test libraries or packages in your project like:

- NUnit
- XUnit
- Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk
- ..

After that, if the small icon besides the name of the project is "C#", you're good to go.

Please make a separate project for your testing.

Answer (score 0):

Add line in your `csproj` file directly as below

```
<GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
```

Or go to the project properties --> packages --> and then enable the option "Produce a package file during build operations"

[image: Project properties for packages]